# typescript return based on input with unique returns

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a typed function that can change its return type based on it's input.

I've seen various examples where we pass a generic type i.e. `<T extend a | b>` but I still have trouble wrapping my head how to make it work for my usage.

For example:

```
type TypeA = number;
type TypeB = number;
type CheckType = {
  a: TypeA;
  b: TypeB;
}

const uniqueStates = (check: CheckType | null) : [TypeA, Type B] | [null, null] => {
  if (check) {
    return [check.a, check.b];
  } else {
    return [null, null]
  }
}
```

where `CheckType` is an object that contains a type `TypeA` and type `TypeB`. When I use this function, the check could be `null, in doing so I would like it to return null.

The desired affect is that when I *do* pass in a valid parameter (`CheckType`), then the return types are ***not*** potentially `null`.

Comment: Could you make this code a [mre] by fixing any typos and declaring any undeclared types and values?  Presumably `Check` is supposed to be `check` but I don't know what your types are.

Comment: So you want *callers* to see that `uniqueStates(null)` is of type `[null, null]` but that `uniqueStates({a: 0, b: 1})` is of type `[TypeA, TypeB]`?  If so then [this](https://tsplay.dev/WyedgW) is how you might proceed, with a generic conditional function. TS doesn't have great support for type checking implementations of such functions (see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) so you need to take care.  Note that your original version should probably return `[TypeA, TypeB] | [null, null]` instead of your version.

Comment: Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz ah yes, the optional on the return makes much more sense, that seems to be what I'm looking for.. although when using that the return type would actually resolve to `TypeA | null` due to the first overloaded function, no?

Comment: What "optional"?  Do you mean a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html)?  I don't see an `any` here... [observe here](https://tsplay.dev/W4PRBW); can you explain what you mean?

Comment: ah, I misread. That is exactly what i was after, please add as an answer so I can approve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for a function's output type to depend on the input type, you must either [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) the function, or make it [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).  These are easy-ish to use for callers, but a bit tricky/annoying to implement.

---

The overload solution looks like this:

```
function uniqueStates(check: CheckType): [TypeA, TypeB];
function uniqueStates(check: null): [null, null];

function uniqueStates(check: CheckType | null) {
  if (check) {
    return [check.a, check.b];
  } else {
    return [null, null]
  }
}
```

Here `uniqueStates()` has two call signatures, and one implementation.  When you call `uniqueStates()`, the compiler picks an appropriate call signature and produces the corresponding return type:

```
const u = uniqueStates({ a: 0, b: 1 });
// const u: [number, number] 
u[0].toFixed(); // okay

const v = uniqueStates(null);
// const v: [null, null]
```

There's a little wrinkle in that you can't pass in a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `CheckType` and `null` anymore, since there is no call signature corresponding to it:

```
const w = uniqueStates(
  Math.random() < 0.5 ? null : { a: 0, b: 1 } // compiler error, no overload matches
);
```

If you really care you could add a third call signature, but you probably don't care.

Note however that the implementation is not guaranteed to be type safe.  Overload implementations are checked loosely.  If you changed the implementation to something else that returns `[TypeA, TypeB] | [null, null]` but does not have the proper input-output relationship, the compiler does not issue a warning:

```
function badUniqueStates(check: CheckType): [TypeA, TypeB];
function badUniqueStates(check: null): [null, null];
function badUniqueStates(check: CheckType | null) {
  if (!check) { return [1, 2]; } else { return [null, null] }; // no error
}
```

So you have to be careful.

---

The generic call signature looks like:

```
declare function uniqueStates<T extends CheckType | null>(
  check: T
): T extends CheckType ? [TypeA, TypeB] : [null, null];
```

Here the return type is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depends on the generic type parameter `T` corresponding to the type of `check`.  If `T` is `CheckType`, then the return type is `[TypeA, TypeB]`.  If `T` is `null`, then the return type is `[null, null]`.

This works well for callers:

```
const u = uniqueStates({ a: 0, b: 1 });
// const u: [number, number] 
u[0].toFixed(); // okay
const v = uniqueStates(null);
// const v: [null, null]
```

And even the union case works, because the return type is [distributive over unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```
const w = uniqueStates(
  Math.random() < 0.5 ? null : { a: 0, b: 1 } // okay
);
// const w: [number, number] | [null, null]
```

Unfortunately you sort of have the opposite problem with implementation; the compiler checks it very strictly, and is unable to narrow the type parameter `T` by checking `check`, so it complains:

```
function uniqueStates<T extends CheckType | null>(
  check: T
): T extends CheckType ? [TypeA, TypeB] : [null, null] {
  if (check) {
    return [check.a, check.b]; // error
  } else {
    return [null, null] // error
  }
}
```

This is a known issue, see [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912).  In order to work around it, you need something like [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) at every `return`:

```
function uniqueStates<T extends CheckType | null>(
  check: T
): T extends CheckType ? [TypeA, TypeB] : [null, null] {
  if (check) {
    return [check.a, check.b] as T extends CheckType ? [TypeA, TypeB] : [null, null];
  } else {
    return [null, null] as T extends CheckType ? [TypeA, TypeB] : [null, null];
  }
}
```

Or you could revert to using a single call signature overload, and rely on loose implementation checking:

```
function uniqueStates<T extends CheckType | null>(
  check: T
): T extends CheckType ? [TypeA, TypeB] : [null, null];

function uniqueStates(check: CheckType | null) {
  if (check) {
    return [check.a, check.b];
  } else {
    return [null, null];
  }
}
```

Both of these have similar issues with regards to type safety; you've now loosened things up to make it compile, but the compiler wouldn't catch "obvious" errors, so you still have to be careful:

```
function badUniqueStatesAssert<T extends CheckType | null>(
  check: T
): T extends CheckType ? [TypeA, TypeB] : [null, null] {
  if (!check) {
    return [1, 2] as T extends CheckType ? [TypeA, TypeB] : [null, null];
  } else {
    return [null, null] as T extends CheckType ? [TypeA, TypeB] : [null, null];
  }
}
```

---

As you can see, callers get a reasonable experience (output type depends on input type) and implementers need to jump through some hoops and/or be very careful.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAdghgtgpgzgBwgYxgAgFLIgGwF5oDeoaaALgJ4LoAqVMAgmgLxpgCuUARjAE4DcJcvTR1qAIRZtOPAUMrU0AYQAWMZAGsx6VsRClSEAFyj6DQfoNcT28RdIBfUEMixEKdAHleASwDmPpA4RM6WpMgA9mBwZGjsYD4AjuwwAMpkEGTwUgAUyGqaJqrqWiIAPtI4OACUJgDa2gwANKYSALpoFXUcVS09OB3MAHwhYQY+AGZoeQUa1aMGi2i8MGTsvGBodfklAHQQLTuau1xt9ksOaDA4cOh6SwYraxtb-X3sVW1Ci05jv99oSLRWLsKTxJIpdKZeA5QhoYxoAAMLWsaAAjGgHNVzqQAPS4wFRGJxeocbh8d7k3gdLpvSoDAHsOqItq7MgRABiPgAHjAACY5bFofGEqAIHw4PhXXi8CK8eFcCLsWIAIgQETgcB8XBwFDiYD5MAmgX5KquADcYJsyColX4VGgfGQAORwNgRMihRxetjQeBIVBoTyW3g4CIQPmjAETeLIMg+KL6iFpDJZOAzEpFWbaWpbRotWxnaOx+OJ8HJFPQ9NHDQmfq57ofHDvT44tAxsBxhObcuQ1MwmtZkraTr0+b3JaTaY18cAxZPdabbazfaHFenNuOK43O5zx6rRevJsthljb1-H2kDtdxNcCMAVQSFahaYzhWU2foDfzrRg4iLYzXqWmx3nyj7Ji+A6zHWTYNnS-QAYsQHdmgoHgc+-bVtBH7DuUY4LJOUw5AAhDORDLAeLx1GiLQAExnJi263ORC5UfBTYdA4bb-CAAJAsSoKsL2lavnCCLIqhJgYlibYivxIKkjIFLSFSHSMsyrLslyvICkKIoRBoEAUHxRKxOaYJPn2VY5PWskEvJaDmopvT0l8vFjA5ADuFkQZhOR7gAspkKi7LwEAGhEUCCmgAA8SK7AArGgAD89JoCYYkmBJqLScK9mReKkrynwsq8H0ERoBEIZhhGaBQJkOxwAC2I+jxLh+u4gYAOJWnwPjIFGgElihwmQXANARBE6S+HGMU0Fc3JZAabrFJoI4VP0Qz+WegLYTQzU2AtS18itn6KKlDRmAW9D-ulR4uQhBGLFOb5zE9SysUuNarrtewbnulzXMxE4PJ993Nq5m6YgCbVDZ2wFJhhVYMJqfBkHNR1WidOFrXhm3bQ8g6iAdoiY8tOOlOdeZXb+t3ORDj0g+MRFkUz86UV9K4HL9xynPCbrzTAi1Y6duFU5d1DNLTHT0yeiEXExu47aQYONg9HH86TQvHaLuPiz+hZ3WrDMcVDvw-Je7bDWWlkifAwZ8DVfIY9rIsU+t9JbXuRP7WMuaC8L5OrZT6AXQbN0y+DcttshNu+VWDuhuGApE8HHv1u9pAvaze4qxzWzfdz33-TtgM7pn+7PEu7GtgDMOW7HIEPrbY0o7cvDowHOvu3jTZeztPsk13btpyIYc04bsuuRXL2kbMs7KxRVdbDRaD0Zrw9B2dofU5L13tEbNcDGbisV3ny-G3LG9k9jo-6xPEeH8ekN1xe7mLA5o2YT5SNponTsWBMsCOIP8rKiXhFlFEUlMQtTGHJUyJIjxUkpLINSYwmQsjZJyHk-JBT8DypVQyxkPIIPMkJFuflbIAngcApyUdXKWy8qAu26ZArBVCuFPkkVopxURIlFKaUMoQKRFA9EjF9JEOanZQkwDPKKWQSpVBo5L4MPftDdyDggA)